# D3D12 ConstantBuffer - Shader receives wrong values

Tags: shaders, directx, hlsl, directx12

im having trouble with one constantbuffer:

```
struct CameraConstData
{
    urd::Matrix projection; // 64 ( 16 floats)
    urd::Matrix view;       // 64 ( 16 floats)
    urd::Vec3 viewPosition; // 12 ( 3 floats)
    urd::Vec3 viewDir;      // 12 ( 3 floats)

    // 104 bytes (26 * 4)
    float offset[26];
};
```

inside the shader its defined like:

```
// desc heap cbv
cbuffer CameraConstBuffer : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 projectionMatrix;
    float4x4 viewMatrix;
    float3 viewPos;
    float3 viewDir;

}
```

now viewdir is always filled with wrong buffer indices.

viewDir.x is the passed y value
viewDir.y is the passed z value
viewDir.z is 0.0

checked it in the shader like:

```
float3 vpos = normalize(float4(viewDir, 0.0)).xyz;
//float value = vpos.x; // uses the passed y value
//float value = vpos.y; // uses the passed z value
color = float4(vpos, 1.0);
```

GPU Debugging shows that the constant buffer looks fine:

[image: gpu constbuffer]

i checked the vectors against the cpu side and they match.

**So why is the shader reading index 36-38 instead of 35-37?**

Its always affecting the 4th member of the struct. If i switch viewPosition with viewDir, viewPosition is false.

Comment: Maybe something to do with alignment perhaps? Have you tried replacing Vec3's with Vec4?

Comment: yes you were right, adding a float after each vec3/float3, fixed the problem. thanks. post as answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aligning members should help. Either replace Vec3 and float3 with Vec4 and float4 or add a float after them.

Comment: @anthom This solves the problem but is more of a workaround than a solution.  The root of the problem is that HLSL default packing is not the same as C++ default packing.  Most C++ compilers provide a mechanism to change packing, such as [`#pragma pack(16)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574061/hlsl-packing-error).